# Want to Implements View.OnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want to implements this method into my coding,but i dont know how to do it,can someone give me some suggestion on how to do it?

Below is the screenshot the coding that i want to use.

[View.ONItemClickListener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M72XH.png)

this is my coding.
ViewOrder.java

```
public class ViewOrder extends AppCompatActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
public static final String JSON_URL = "http://dashberry.com/strack/mobile/viewOrder.php";
private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_order);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    sendRequest();
}

private void sendRequest(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewOrder.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
        });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String json){

    ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
    CustomList cl = new CustomList(this, ParseJSON.itemName,ParseJSON.origin,ParseJSON.destination);
    listView.setAdapter(cl);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ItemDetail.class);
    //ParseJSON<String> map = (ParseJSON)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    //HashMap<String,String> map = (HashMap)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
   // String empId = map.get(ParseJSON.itemName).toString();
   // intent.putExtra("item_id", empId);
    startActivity(intent);
 }

}
```

ParseJSON.java

```
public class ParseJSON {
public static String[] itemName;
public static String[] origin;
public static String[] destination;

public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "itemName";
public static final String KEY_ORIGIN = "origin";
public static final String KEY_DESTINATION = "destination";

private JSONArray users = null;

private String json;



public ParseJSON(String json){

    this.json = json;
}

protected void parseJSON(){
    JSONObject jsonObject=null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

        itemName = new String[users.length()];
        origin = new String[users.length()];
        destination = new String[users.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
            JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
            itemName[i] = jo.getString(KEY_NAME);
            origin[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ORIGIN);
            destination[i] = jo.getString(KEY_DESTINATION);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

So basically what i want is when user click the item in the list,it will take the user to the next activity with some data(itemName).

Answer (score 0):

implement onItemClick like

```
        @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
                //start a new Activity via Intent
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(this, ItemDetail.class);

//you can putExtra only position or id
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
```

You Should Create Anther Activity called ItemDetail you can get id and position by add this code in `onCreate()` to know which item was clicked

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String position = intent.getStringExtra("position");
String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
```

Comment: thanks for comment at my question,it really help me to think. Does this mean its impossible for me to carry one of the data in the list? for example i just want to carry the itemname of the list that we click. @NgimaSherpa

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can use putExtra() method to send data from one activity and can get the data in other activity that was sent form the previous activity.